# Comparing php variable using the LIKE sql operator with mixed datatypes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to be able to search using name, phone number, customer, email, etc. all in the same search field. But some of the columns are INT and some are VARCHAR and I'm getting a syntax error and I'm not sure why. I tried using CAST to resolve the issue but I'm still getting an error.

**PHP**

```
$search  = $_POST['search'];
var_dump($search);
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CAST(custid as VARCHAR) LIKE '%$search%' OR firstname LIKE '%$search%' OR lastname LIKE '%$search%' OR CAST(primaryphone as VARCHAR) LIKE '%'$search%'' OR CAST(secondaryphone as VARCHAR) LIKE '%$search%' OR email LIKE '%$search%'";
    $statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
} catch(PDOException $Exception) {
    echo "Error: " . $Exception;
    die();
}
```

**Error**

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR) LIKE '%George%' OR firstname LIKE '%George%' OR lastname LIKE '%George%' at line 1'

**TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    custid int(6),
    firstname varchar(20),
    lastname varchar(20),
    primaryphone int(20),
    secondaryphone int(20),
    email varchar(40),
);
```

Comment: I think first you have to use OR instead of "||"

Comment: I changed them to OR but still get the same error message. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need to provide the field length. `CAST(custid as VARCHAR(12))`

Comment: And maybe another problem could be the prepared statement. You directly inserting the "variables" instead of binding them. See mysqli_stmt_bind_param [link](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) you can only cast to:

> BINARY[(N)]
>
> CHAR[(N)]
>
> DATE
>
> DATETIME
>
> DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
>
> SIGNED [INTEGER]
>
> TIME
>
> UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

So if you really have to cast your `int` into something, use `CHAR` or `CHAR(20)` for that matter.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I should have read into the CAST docs a little more before hand.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to create another variable and add it to the dump, and it would search for those columns of type int at the same time $search checks those varchar columns.

Comment: But the field in the database still has the wrong (different) type, so he need to convert/cast it anyways.